# ¿Qué método es más eficiente para referenciar valores?

Tags: java, método, eficiencia

Quisiera saber cuál de estos métodos es más eficiente. Estos métodos están dentro de la misma clase Rectangulo2.

1. Primera forma usando los métodos getter:

   ```
   public boolean puntoCorrectos(){
        return getPuntoAX() == getPuntoBX() && getPuntoCX() == getPuntoDX() && 
               getPuntoAY() == getPuntoDY() && getPuntoCY() == getPuntoBY();
   }
   ```
2. Segunda forma usando las variables directas

   ```
   public boolean puntosCorrecto(){
       return puntoAX == puntoBX && puntoCX == puntoDX && puntoAY == puntoDY &&
               puntoCY == puntoBY;
   }
   ```
3. Tercera forma usando una referencia

   ```
   public boolean puntossCorrectos(Rectangulo2 r){
       return r.puntoAX == r.puntoBX && r.puntoCX == r.puntoDX && r.puntoAY == r.puntoDY &&
               r.puntoCY == r.puntoBY;
   }
   ```

Comment: Para mi, la segunda.. es un metodo dentro de la clase por ende deberias referencias con `this.puntoAX`. La tercera puede que funcione, pero es raro que un objecto del tipo Rectangulo se envie asi mismo a una funcion propia de su clase.

Comment: la segunda es la mejor, hace uso directamente de sus atributos

Comment: La segunda es mejor, solo separaría un poco para limpieza de código 
if(puntoAX!=puntoBX){
 return false;
}
así en todos, crece tu código verticalmente pero disminuye horizontal.

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta es: **depende**.

La primera opción es la más adecuada si es que tu clase `Rectangulo2` permite tener subclases y que ellas puedan sobreescribir los métodos `get`. Esto es, la primera forma permite el uso de la abstracción y polimorfismo, cosa que la segunda y tercera opción no permiten.

La segunda opción es la más adecuada si es que tu clase `Rectangulo2` no permite subclases o si es que la validación debe ser sobre los valores directos más que en los getters. En particular, esta implementación es más sencilla de leer para otros programadores en lugar de la primera, pero fuerza a que si alguna clase hija quisiera cambiar este comportamiento, tenga que sobreescribir el método por completo.

La tercera opción es la más adecuada si fuese un método estático y, de preferencia, estuviese definido en una clase utilitaria (comúnmente conocida como util o helper). Así, podrías llamar al método `Rectangulo2#puntossCorrectos` sin necesidad de tener una instancia de la clase para invocarlo, pero sí necesitarías de una o más instancias para pasar como argumento al método. Una ventaja que tendría el método al ser diseñado como estático es que puedes hacer una validación de nulo. Parece ridículo, pero esta línea es propensa a NPE:

```
r.puntoCorrecto();
```

Porque `r` puede ser nulo. Claro, puedes agregar una validación antes de ello, o podrías olvidarte de agregar ese `if` allí y solo agregarlo en tu implementación estática:

```
public static boolean puntossCorrectos(Rectangulo2 r){
    return r != null && r.puntoAX == r.puntoBX && r.puntoCX == r.puntoDX && r.puntoAY == r.puntoDY &&
        r.puntoCY == r.puntoBY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Todo dependerá de la forma en que se encuentren relacionadas las clases en tu modelo. Por ejemplo sí es por medio de una relación de uso, lo correcto sería el método 3, pues la clase nada más recibe un objeto, hace lo que desee y ya se debe desentender de dicho objeto.

En tu caso, como todos los métodos están dentro de la misma clase, lo correcto sería el número dos, pues sí utilizas el número uno, estarías haciendo una cola de llamadas de métodos. La número uno solo sería correcto sí los valores están en otra clase, pues cumples el principio de encapsulación.

Finalmente es mejor que no uses el `this`, es innecesario (sé que son tecnologías aparte, pero desde la Versión Visual Studio 2015, pone como recomendación quitar los this, para la simplificación de código y siguiendo el principio de programación KISS (Keep it simply, stupid) Mantenerlo simple y estúpido), el this solo debe ser usado cuando en un método haya una declaración de una variable que lleve por nombre el mismo al de un atributo de la clase ejemplo:

```
public class MiClase{
  private int varCompar;

  public bool Comparar(int varCompar)
  {
    return this.variable == variable;
  }
}
```

Para entender más puedes buscar sobre, relaciones en POO, Principio KISS Programación y Principios de POO

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estamos de acuerdo que la tercera opción no tiene sentido en el caso de esta clase en particular, ya que no tiene sentido pasar `this` como un parámetro a la función.

Entre la primera y la segunda opción, intuitivamente la segunda tiene mas sentido.

Pero, no pienses, que la segunda opción necesariamente vaya a ser mas eficiente que la primera. En la práctica, el JIT es capaz de analizar la primera opción y eliminar métodos sencillos como `getPuntoAX()` y reemplazarlos con accesos directos a las variables, efectivamente transformando el código en algo que se parece a tu segunda opción.

Ahora bien, si decides usar `this.` en frente de las variables o no, eso es una cuestión de estilo nada mas, y no tiene ningún impacto en la eficiencia del código.